# Create a custom progress bar based on icon

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a custom progress bar implementing a UI concept which makes sense in the application context, but I don't know exactly how to do it

I've search for some packages but none of them seems to fullfil my needs, so I guess I'll need to create a widget from scratch, I would like to have some directions on it. The intented result is as follow the image. The progress is indicated by how many boxes are painted green, naturally it reachs 100% when all boxes are painted.
[image: progress bar using box icon]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what resolution you need. Do you need half boxes? or just full?
For example, if you have 10 boxes, can your progress resolution round to the nearest 10%, so from 0-9% no boxes are filled, and then 10-19% one box is filled? And so on...
If you wanted 15 boxes, your resolution would be 100% / 15 = 6.25 % per box.

If having fully filled in boxes will work. here is some code to get you started.
(The purple slider is only there to set the _progress variable).
[image]
[image]
[image]

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _progress = 0;

  final double progressMin = 0;
  final double progressMax = 100;
  final int numBoxes = 10;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(_progress.toStringAsFixed(1)),
            Slider(
                value: _progress,
                min: progressMin,
                max: progressMax,
                onChanged: (newVal) {
                  setState(() {
                    _progress = newVal;
                  });
                }),
            Row(
              children: [
                for (int i = 0; i < numBoxes; i++)
                  Icon(
                    Icons.check_box_outline_blank_rounded,
                    color: _progress >= (i + 1) * (progressMax / numBoxes)
                        ? Colors.green[600]
                        : Colors.grey[400],
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This definitely gave me interesting ideas to work it, thanks! Also, I was trying to not just paint half boxes, but render halfboxes, this is [the best result](https://imgur.com/a/UUoZGvs) I got so far. It's a stack with a progressbar behind a repeteable image (which is the icon itself) of a transparent box. But your solution is way better to determine how many boxes gonna show up, thanks for your answer!

Comment: No problem! Do you want higher resolution? I needed to solve a while ago for my app. What I ended up doing was generating a png and then changing the height (vertical slider) depending on where the progress was. So in your case, you could generate a greyed out image, and then a green image (both pngs). create a stack with the grey on the bottom, and then the top is the green. wrap the green in an Align widget (align set to center left) and then wrap in a ClipRRect widget. Also in the align widget should be widthFactor set to your progress (as a %). this will let any % progress show correctly

Comment: Ran out of of characters in my last comment. Let me know if you want to see an example, I can go dig up that old code

Comment: Looks a nice solution too, if it doesn't bother you, I would like to see your example

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer that gives essentially infinite resolution.

You need a 2 images (pngs) to make this work. An 'empty' image and a 'full' image. Think of the empty image on the bottom and the full image on top, and you are cropping the right side of the full image to show various progress points. The grey is empty and the green is full.

Important note: This is much much much easier if both images are the exact same dimensions. You could make it work if they weren't, but it seems like a huge headache.

[image: Full image on top on stack]

[image: Empty image on bottom of stack]

---

[image]
[image]

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double _progress = 0;

  final double progressMin = 0;
  final double progressMax = 100;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(_progress.toStringAsFixed(1)),
            Slider(
                value: _progress,
                min: progressMin,
                max: progressMax,
                onChanged: (newVal) {
                  setState(() {
                    _progress = newVal;
                  });
                }),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/empty.png'),
                  ClipRRect(
                    child: Align(
                      // align center left because we want a left to right progress. If you wanted bottom to top, this would be bottomCenter and use heightFactor instead
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      // map _progress to a range of 0 to 1 (or set the min and max on the slider to 0 and 1)
                      widthFactor: 0 +
                          ((1 - 0) / (progressMax - progressMin)) * (_progress),
                      child: Image.asset('assets/full.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: Just realized that the children of the stack don't need to be images. They could be a row of icons like in my first answer. This should still work the same way. This would also allow for setting number of boxes like in my first answer